# Thread-safe BitArray

Tags: c#, thread-safety, concurrency, bitwise

**Notes:**

- supports 64-bit platforms only
- `ulong` used where negative values make no sense
- library functions are assumed to be correct (whether they actually do what I want or not is a subject for another post)
- the thread-safe implementation will ideally be refactored so that it ends up in another class but this way makes it easier for me to ensure correctness during development

This is my first real adventure in writing a thread-safe class. With the above notes taken into account, *did I screw anything up in a way that might violate my thread-safe claim or am I performing any unncessary operations?*

**Code:**

```
public sealed class BitVector : IEnumerable<bool>
{
    private readonly long[] m_bits;
    private readonly bool m_isThreadSafe;
    private readonly ulong m_length;

    private long m_version = 0L;

    public bool this[long index] {
        get {
            return this[checked((ulong)index)];
        }
        set {
            this[checked((ulong)index)] = value;
        }
    }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public bool this[ulong index] {
        get {
            if (m_length > index) {
                if (m_isThreadSafe) {
                    return BTConcurrent.AtomicRead(ref m_bits[(index / 64UL)]).IsBitSet(checked((int)index.Mod64()));
                }
                else {
                    return m_bits[(index / 64UL)].IsBitSet(checked((int)index.Mod64()));
                }
            }
            else {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(index));
            }
        }
        set {
            if (m_length > index) {
                if (value) {
                    if (m_isThreadSafe) {
                        unchecked { BTConcurrent.AtomicIncrement(ref m_version); }

                        BTConcurrent.AtomicSetBit(ref m_bits[unchecked(index / 64UL)], checked((int)index.Mod64()));
                    }
                    else {
                        m_bits[unchecked(index / 64UL)].SetBit(checked((int)index.Mod64()));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (m_isThreadSafe) {
                        unchecked { BTConcurrent.AtomicIncrement(ref m_version); }

                        BTConcurrent.AtomicClearBit(ref m_bits[unchecked(index / 64UL)], checked((int)index.Mod64()));
                    }
                    else {
                        m_bits[unchecked(index / 64UL)].ClearBit(checked((int)index.Mod64()));
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(index));
            }
        }
    }
    public long Length {
        get {
            return checked((long)UnsignedLength);
        }
    }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public ulong UnsignedLength {
        get {
            return m_length;
        }
    }

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public BitVector(ulong length, long initBitPattern, bool isThreadSafe) {
        m_bits = new long[((length / 64UL) + Convert.ToUInt64(length.Mod64().IsPositive()))];
        m_isThreadSafe = isThreadSafe;
        m_length = length;

        if (initBitPattern != 0L) {
            SetAll(initBitPattern);
        }
    }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public BitVector(ulong length, bool isThreadSafe) : this(length, 0L, isThreadSafe) { }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public BitVector(ulong length) : this(length, false) { }

    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public void And(long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        And(this, bitPattern, count);
    }
    public void AndAll(long bitPattern) {
        And(bitPattern, unchecked((ulong)m_bits.LongLength));
    }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public void Clear(ulong count) {
        SetAll(0L, count);
    }
    public void ClearAll() {
        SetAll(0L, unchecked((ulong)m_bits.LongLength));
    }
    public IEnumerator<bool> GetEnumerator() {
        if (m_isThreadSafe) {
            var versionSnapshot = BTConcurrent.AtomicRead(ref m_version);

            for (var i = 0UL; i < UnsignedLength; i++) {
                if (versionSnapshot == BTConcurrent.AtomicRead(ref m_version)) {
                    yield return this[i];
                }
                else {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(message: "data was mutated during enumeration, unable to continue");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0UL; i < UnsignedLength; i++) {
                yield return this[i];
            }
        }
    }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public void Or(long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        Or(this, bitPattern, count);
    }
    public void OrAll(long bitPattern) {
        Or(bitPattern, unchecked((ulong)m_bits.LongLength));
    }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public void Not(long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        Not(this, bitPattern, count);
    }
    public void NotAll(long bitPattern) {
        Not(bitPattern, unchecked((ulong)m_bits.LongLength));
    }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public void SetAll(long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        Set(this, bitPattern, count);
    }
    public void SetAll(long bitPattern) {
        SetAll(bitPattern, ((ulong)m_bits.LongLength));
    }
    public void SetAll() {
        SetAll(-1L);
    }
    public void SetEven() {
        OrAll(6148914691236517205L /* equivalent to 1010....1010 */);
    }
    public void SetOdd() {
        OrAll(-6148914691236517206L /* equivalent to 0101....0101 */);
    }
    [CLSCompliant(false)]
    public void Xor(long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        Xor(this, bitPattern, count);
    }
    public void XorAll(long bitPattern) {
        Xor(bitPattern, ((ulong)m_bits.LongLength));
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private static void And(BitVector bitVector, long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        if (count > unchecked((ulong)bitVector.m_bits.Length)) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(count));
        }

        if (bitVector.m_isThreadSafe) {
            unchecked { BTConcurrent.AtomicIncrement(ref bitVector.m_version); }

            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                BTConcurrent.AtomicAndAssign(ref bitVector.m_bits[i], bitPattern);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                bitVector.m_bits[i] &= bitPattern;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void Not(BitVector bitVector, long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        if (count > unchecked((ulong)bitVector.m_bits.Length)) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(count));
        }

        if (bitVector.m_isThreadSafe) {
            unchecked { BTConcurrent.AtomicIncrement(ref bitVector.m_version); }

            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                BTConcurrent.AtomicNotAssign(ref bitVector.m_bits[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                bitVector.m_bits[i] = (~bitPattern);
            }
        }
    }
    private static void Or(BitVector bitVector, long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        if (count > unchecked((ulong)bitVector.m_bits.Length)) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(count));
        }

        if (bitVector.m_isThreadSafe) {
            unchecked { BTConcurrent.AtomicIncrement(ref bitVector.m_version); }

            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                BTConcurrent.AtomicOrAssign(ref bitVector.m_bits[i], bitPattern);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                bitVector.m_bits[i] |= bitPattern;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void Set(BitVector bitVector, long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        if (count > unchecked((ulong)bitVector.m_bits.Length)) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(count));
        }

        if (bitVector.m_isThreadSafe) {
            unchecked { BTConcurrent.AtomicIncrement(ref bitVector.m_version); }

            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                BTConcurrent.AtomicWrite(ref bitVector.m_bits[i], bitPattern);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                bitVector.m_bits[i] = bitPattern;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void Xor(BitVector bitVector, long bitPattern, ulong count) {
        if (count > unchecked((ulong)bitVector.m_bits.Length)) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(count));
        }

        if (bitVector.m_isThreadSafe) {
            unchecked { BTConcurrent.AtomicIncrement(ref bitVector.m_version); }

            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                BTConcurrent.AtomicXorAssign(ref bitVector.m_bits[i], bitPattern);
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                bitVector.m_bits[i] ^= bitPattern;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show us the `BTConcurrent` class also?

Comment: @JanDotNet, I have no real objection to sharing the code but do feel like doing so could distract from analyzing whether or not this particular class behaves properly. That said, see: https://github.com/ByteTerrace/ByteTerrace.CSharp.Core/blob/master/BTConcurrent.cs. Please note that I'm not claiming the code is correct since, like I said, that's for another post.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 thanks, I had a look but couldn't find that, certainly seems to meet all my assumptions (classic examples of CAS).

Answer (score 4):

## Thread Safety

This looks mildly terrifying... I'm going to assume that all the `Atomic*` methods in `BTConcurrent` are also themselves thread-safe.

Unless I'm missing something, your code is only thread-save on an individual entry (each `ulong` in `m_bits`) level (i.e. you can't end up with a 'broken' ulong), and is otherwise completely unsafe.

### Multi-Entry Mutators

All of the methods which operate on multiple entries in `m_bits` are dodgy, because even though the individual operations may be thread safe, an `And` might 'overtake' an `Or` running at the same time from any index (i.e. it's unhelpful to ask which runs first), which doesn't sound like intended behaviour (and judging by the presence of `GetEnumerator()` is *not*.

That wasn't very clear, so a very simple example. If you start with 2 entries (`ulongs`) in `m_bits`, but `0UL`, and then on separate threads run `SetAll()` and `ClearAll()`, it is possible to end up with any of four outcomes. Indeed, for `n` entries, the scheduling may run in such a way that a 'simultaneous' `SetAll()` and `ClearAll()` could produce *any* of the `2^n` binary patterns possible.

I think we can all agree that calling `SetAll()` and `ClearAll()` should either results in nothing but `1s` or nothing but `0s`. It might be fun for you to try this situation out with a big BitVector or two, and many `SetAll()` `ClearAll()` calls, to see if you can get some crazy results. This is essentially the same reason you have methods for just to read/write a `ulong`, because on a 32bit machine, it is possible that one half of the 64bit number will be set by one thread, and then overwritten by another which then writes the other half, before that is overwritten by the original thread, leaving you with a 'broken' `ulong`. Incidentally, I can think of no reason why this code should be 64bit only, as long as you use proper atomic reads and writes (which I'm assuming those in `BTConcurrent` are) then it should work on any machine.

### `m_version`

(I take it is only used for snapshotting?) In each of the mutators, you increment the `m_version` independently of changing `m_bits`: this means that there is time when the version is unchanged but the data has changed, which will breaks `GetEnumerator`. This means, if you start with all `0s`, and call `SetAll()`, it will update the version before doing anything else. At this point, `GetEnumerator()` may run, remember this *new* version, and start yielding values (lots of `0s`). `SetAll()` may overtake `GetEnumerator()`, and then `GetEnumerator()` will start yielding `1s`.

As an aside, a comment somewhere explaining that `m_version` is meaningless without `m_isThreadSafe` set would be appreciated.

### `GetEnumerator()`

This is faulty owing to the issues with `m_version` (i.e. may appear to run fine, but actually it is lying). However, even more fundamentally, you are checking `m_version`, and then returning a value. There is no reason that `m_version` and the data itself shouldn't change in this time.

## How to fix it?

### Easy `lock`ing

(My apologies if you've tried locking already and it's too slow; this is worth adding for other people).

A reliable, simple, and relatively difficult-to-get-wrong solution would be to throw locks at your code. C# has the lovely [`lock`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement which makes this easy and keeps the code clean.

Essentially, it allows you to exclude other threads from access blocks of code whilst another 'holds' the lock (underneath it is monitors and lots of memory barriers). The simplest solution would be to just lock all your code which writes (reading is another kettle of fish) so that only one thread can change the state at a time.

For example:

```c#
private readonly object LocalLock = new object(); // per-instance mutex provider
private static void And(BitVector bitVector, long bitPattern, ulong count) {
    if (count > unchecked((ulong)bitVector.m_bits.Length)) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(count));
    }

    if (bitVector.m_isThreadSafe) {
        lock (LocalLock)
        {
            m_version++;

            for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
                bitVector.m_bits[i] &= bitPattern;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0UL; i < count; i++) {
            bitVector.m_bits[i] &= bitPattern;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've removed all the `BTConcurrent` stuff, because the `lock` keyword provides strong guarantees about memory access and such (which makes it relatively expensive, but easy and dependable).

Other than the costs of keeping the memory in sync, this simple locking scheme can leave threads stalled for a long time when in theory they could be doing work. If you lock your reads as well, then the enumerator will block writes (it won't ever fail, though!).

### Complex 'Locking'

Using `lock` is easy, but can stall threads completely when they *could* be doing work. Ignoring reading for the moment, suppose an `And` is run just after an `Or`. In theory, you could `Or` one of the `ulongs` in m_bits, and then `And` it immediately afterwards, but with dumb locking, the `And` has to wait until the `Or` has modified *every* entry in `m_bits`.

Unfortunately, this is a non-trivial data-structure to make concurrent, so there is no 'just use CAS to make it faster' option, the cost won't be with the locks but with the blocking itself.

You *could* write some terrifying code that allows these operations to 'chase' each other along the array. This would be a lot of effort, and would require per-entry symbols to 'lock' on. The simplest solution would probably to have a per-entry `version` count, and use 'CAS' (Compare and Set (Exchange)) (See [`System.Threading.Interlocked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx)) to efficiently block on each entry. This would only apply to those methods that modify multiple entries; the indexer would be different, and you'd have to decide the behaviour (you'd have to decide it before writing the other code, though, because it will definitely influence the implementation). Simply performing atomic operations as you are at the moment will not simply work because of issues with reading, even if the write-ordering is a non-issue.

### Reading

You could make `GetEnumerator()` lock up the object and make a copy to ensure a complete and meaningful read (locking and `yield return` might create problems if you never fully consume the enumerable, but perhaps this is OK with you). If not, you need to check the version before reading (with a lock, to ensure any updates from that version are committed), and after reading, to ensure that it hasn't changed since that version would applied (this still needs a [memory-barrier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.memorybarrier(v=vs.110).aspx) of some sort to ensure that your thread has the most up-to-date version, but wouldn't need a full lock).

## Style

I've not seen `m_` used in C# (C++ background?), you may want to check out the C# coding conventions, but the exposed API looks mostly fine.

## Postamble

As far as I'm aware, a lot of accurate information about threading (C#/.NET) can be found [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx), and is, in my opinion, also very well written. It has lots of examples - which having written your code you'll  be able to relate to and understand why they are important - that are worth going through. I should really go back and read it myself...

## Thread Racing Pictures

This picture shows one interleaving

[image: Racing between <code>XAll</code> and <code>GetEnumerator</code> 1]

This picture shows another

[image: Racing between <code>XAll</code> and <code>GetEnumerator</code> 2]

This pictures shows the same with an added `m_writer_count`, which indicates when the data-structure is being modified, so that `GetEnumerable` can detect it and throw.

[image: Possible solution to ensure detection of data-structure mutation]

*If* you don't mind these kinds of errors, then there is no need for `m_version`, and judicious use of thread-safe atomic reads and writes as present in your original code is sufficient to prevent any 'broken' or 'corrupted' `ulong`s from being `yield`ed by `GetEnumerator`.

Comment: The potential for `XAll` style methods to "race" is absolutely intentional and should be allowed as long as any active enumerators are forced to terminate by a mutation. You're absolutely right that there is a bug in my enumerator code that could allow a single "corrupted" value to be yielded though. Correct me if I'm wrong, this bug should be able to be resolved by reading the value first and then verifying that the version hasn't changed before yielding, yeah?

Comment: @Kittoes0124 sorry, I fear I misunderstood your question when I wrote my (now deleted) comment. To ensure that the state hasn't changed from the start of `GetEnumerable()` when you `yield` each value, it is insufficient to check `m_version`, because this is updated before the mutators actually do anything. If you are happy with the racing writes (which seem a bit odd to me), then you can perhaps resolve this issue by adding a counter to indicate the number of active writers, which you must check is 0 at the start and before each yield, as well the version having not changed.

Comment: Huh, maybe I'm just daft but how would `var result = AtomicRead(value); if (AtomicRead(version) == snapshot) { yield return result; } else { throw ...; }` allow corrupt values through? Incrementing the version is the moment the setter is entered should force an error in the reader.

Comment: To explain the "racing writes", I allow them because they're not technically incorrect; definitely weird but there are many scenarios where the end result will be valid regardless of which thread "wins." I do love the idea of adding a way to prevent them by default though; think it could be implemented in a way where the user can opt-in without compromising thread-safety?

Comment: @Kittoes0124 perhaps I'm missing what you mean by 'corrupted'; the `ulong`s cannot be corrupted, because you are using atomic reads (which all look correct), so there is no need to worry about that. The issue I see is that if `XAll` is running at the same time as `GetEnumerator()` then it is possible for, say, the first entry in `m_bits` to be updated by `XAll`, then the first and second yielded by `GetEnumerator()`, and then the second be update, all without `m_version` changing. Perhaps you aren't worried about this either: if not, I don't see a need for `m_version` at all!

Comment: @Kittoes0124 (added some pictures to the end of my answer to hopefully better explain what I mean). Regarding opt-in `XAll` synchronisation, I'm not sure what you mean by opt-in, but it will be very fiddly to implement efficiently. A very simple exclusive `lock`ing mechanism would suffice for correctness, but you'd need to read-up on Monitors and/or CAS to implement in such a way as to prevent the stalling described in the answer. No reasonable solution springs to mind, but this is certainly something I'll keep thinking about...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63551/discussion-between-kittoes0124-and-visualmelon).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need perform divisions like `index / 64UL` (where index is `ulong`) in an unchecked context since overflow will never occur in this case. Also you don't need `UL` suffix for `64`.

---

Are you sure you need such "big" types for indexers parameters as `long` and `ulong`? I would work with `int` and `uint` only since it is more than enough.

---

In CLS compliant version of the indexer you should check if argument is negative and cast it to `ulong` without checked context:

```
public bool this[long index]
{
    get
    {
        if (index < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index), index, "Index is negative.");

        return this[(ulong)index];
    }
    set
    {
        if (index < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index), index, "Index is negative.");

        this[(ulong)index] = value;
    }
}
```

---

Place opening curly braces on new line :)